# Python problem with maths formula for items in list replacement

Tags: python

for some reasons the "-26" is not going through in my code– when i print out 'newnum' the newnumber for out-of-range numbers is not what it should be. does anybody know what the problem is here?

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
zipped = dict(zip(letters, numbers))
zipped2 = dict(zip(numbers, letters))
punc = [',','.','!','?','!', ' ']

def decode(codeword, x):
    numbercode = []

    for letters in codeword:
        if letters not in punc:
            numbercode.append(zipped[letters])
    newnum = []
    for num in numbercode:
        newnum.append(num+x)
    lettercode = []
    for num in newnum:
        if num+x >= 25:
            num = num+x-26
        lettercode.append(zipped2[num])
    lettercode = ' '.join(lettercode)
    return lettercode


decode('tiger', 11)
```

Comment: If `num + x == 25` you convert it to `-1`. I doubt that you intend that. Why not simply `num % 26`? Also -- you already added `x` once, so why add it again? You could also just use a list comprehension, something like `newnum = [(num + x)%26 for num in numbercode]`

Comment: Don't initialize "letters" and "numbers" manually! You can do this for the same result

`import string`
`letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)`
`numbers = list(range(26))`

Comment: yep you're so right. however, doing that, i'm getting a letter 'p' for 't' when it should be 'e', so the code doesn't seem to work for the out-of-range letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the modulo operation `%` for this kind of usage.

If you don't want to, the problem in your code is that you are comparing by adding `x` again. You should compare `x>25` and assign `num=num-26`.

So the solution would be:

```py
def decode(codeword, x):
    numbercode = []
    for letter in codeword:
        if letter not in punc:
            numbercode.append(zipped[letter])
    newnum = []
    for num in numbercode:
        newnum.append(num + x)
    lettercode = []
    for num in newnum:
        if num > 25:
            num = num - 26
        lettercode.append(zipped2[num])
    lettercode = "".join(lettercode)
    return lettercode
```

The solution using the modulo operation is:

```py
def decode(codeword, x):
    numbercode = []
    for letter in codeword:
        if letter not in punc:
            numbercode.append(zipped[letter])
    newnum = []
    for num in numbercode:
        newnum.append(num + x)
    lettercode = []
    for num in newnum:
        lettercode.append(zipped2[num % 26])
    lettercode = "".join(lettercode)
    return lettercode
```

Finally, a short version of your code can be done since you are updating items of the lists in each loop without the necessity of all these loops:

```py
def decode_short(codeword, x):
    lettercode = []
    for letter in codeword:
        if letter not in punc:
            lettercode.append(zipped2[(zipped[letter] + x) % 26])
    return "".join(lettercode)
```

And even shorter with [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```py
def decode_very_short(codeword, x):
    return "".join([zipped2[(zipped[l] + x) % 26] for l in codeword if l not in punc])
```

Comment: i don't have a high enough reputation to thumb this up but thank you so much for this clear explanation. i really appreciate this